# ESOCKETTIMEDOUT Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions for Firebase together with my Firebase Realtime Database in order to do some data management for my app.

One of my functions though seems to get terminated since it takes about 100-150 seconds to complete. This happens with error : `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT`.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Here is my function:

```
function getTopCarsForUserWithPreferences(userId, genres) {
  const pathToCars = admin.database().ref('cars');

  pathTocars.orderByChild("IsTop").equalTo(true).once("value").then(function(snapshot) { 
      return writeSuggestedCars(userId, genres, snapshot);
  }).catch(reason => {
    console.log(reason)
  })
}

function writeSuggestedCars(userId, genres, snapshot) {
    const carsToWrite = {};
    var snapCount = 0
    snapshot.forEach(function(carSnapshot) {
        snapCount += 1
        const carDict = carSnapshot.val();
        const carGenres = carDict.taCarGenre;
        const genre_one = genres[0];
        const genre_two = genres[1];

        if (carGenres[genre_one] === true ||carGenres[genre_two] == true) {
            carsToWrite[carSnapshot.key] = carDict
    }

        if (snapshot.numChildren() - 1 == snapCount) {
            const pathToSuggest = admin.database().ref('carsSuggested').child(userId);
            pathToSuggest.set(carsToWrite).then(snap => {

            }).catch(reason => {
            console.log(reason)
             });
        }
    });
}
```

The `getTopCarsForUserWithPreferences` gets called when a user adds preferences. Also the `cars` table has about 50k entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to return everytime you use a async task.

Edit: you return 'writeSuggestedCars' but I think it never returns a value. I do not have a compiler, but I thought it was return Promise.resolved(). Can you insert it where I putted 'HERE'?

Maybe this will work:

```
function getTopCarsForUserWithPreferences(userId, genres) {
  const pathToCars = admin.database().ref('cars');

  return pathTocars.orderByChild("IsTop").equalTo(true).once("value").then(function(snapshot) { 
      return writeSuggestedCars(userId, genres, snapshot);
  }).catch(reason => {
    console.log(reason)
  })
}

function writeSuggestedCars(userId, genres, snapshot) {
    const carsToWrite = {};
    var snapCount = 0
    snapshot.forEach(function(carSnapshot) {
        snapCount += 1
        const carDict = carSnapshot.val();
        const carGenres = carDict.taCarGenre;
        const genre_one = genres[0];
        const genre_two = genres[1];

        if (carGenres[genre_one] === true ||carGenres[genre_two] == true) {
            carsToWrite[carSnapshot.key] = carDict
    }

        if (snapshot.numChildren() - 1 == snapCount) {
            const pathToSuggest = admin.database().ref('carsSuggested').child(userId);
            return pathToSuggest.set(carsToWrite).then(snap => {
                // 'HERE' I think return promise/Promise.resolve() will work
            }).catch(reason => {
            console.log(reason)
             });
        }
    });
}
```